# PHPMyAdmin muestra pantalla en blanco, ¿cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Soy nuevo en phpmyadmin. Tengo instalado XAMPP, y cuando intento ingresar a localhost:8080/phpmyadmin,ñ me carga una pantalla en blanco.

Este problema surgió porque modifiqué la línea:

$cfg[‘ExecTimeLimit’] = 300;

a

$cfg[‘ExecTimeLimit’] = 0;

en el archivo config.default.php; hice esto para poder solucionar un problema de tiempo de ejecución.

Me gustaría preguntar cómo se corrige este problema o qué puedo hacer, llevo unos dias en esto y no quiero desinstalar y volver a instalar XAMPP cada vez que pase esto.

Comment: Has revisado qué sale en los logs? Posiblemente hay un error y la página en blanco indica que no termina de procesar los scripts para dar una salida HTML

Comment: Que tal gracias por tu comentario, revise los logs pero no encontre nada; lo solucione añadiendo la linea $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000; en el archivo  config.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el problema añadiendo la linea:

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 6000;

en el archivo

config.inc.php